# PHP password_verify always returning false

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, basic-authentication

Hi there I am trying to hash my passwords with password_hash() in PHP. This part is fine but to compare the hash is returning false no matter what. To log in I check the user account database and grab the password hash then compare it to the password typed in. My code looks like this:

```
$password = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
$hash = $row["password"];
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // CREATE SESSION VARIABLES //
}
else{
     header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
}
```

As you can see the password that is typed in is brought over in the HTTP header. I didn't think this would mess with the password string as I can compare this directly to the password in the database (without hashing). Any ideas? I have triple checked my version of PHP and I can hash the password so that's not it.

Comment: Have you checked that the arguments you are giving to `password_verify` are what you expect them to be?

Comment: well the password in the database has been hashed with password_hash() function. This is then identified and grabbed by the username entered and the company ID entered. Then the entered password is compared with the hashed password with the password_verify() function. however it always returns false

Comment: No I mean have you manually checked and made sure that the values of `$password` and `$hash` are the correct values as retrieved, whether they verify or not.

Comment: yes just doubled checked all coming through fine

Comment: Do I have to hash the typed in password and compare it to the hashed password stored in the database? I was of the understanding that each time you hash a string it'll come out different hence the password_verify() function.

Comment: I'm thinking agnostically to what functions you are running.  Those functions were released in the last major version of PHP you see.  Try hashing the incoming password the same way as the stored one and see if they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

So nothing wrong with the password_verify() function. There was an added bit of string in the password_hash() function. I copy and pasted this function from the official documentation:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

The ."\n" bit at the end was not being accounted for at the verify function. This was only here due to the coping and pasting so once I removed it, it was fine. Hope this helps others in the future.